# How to set disk1's MBR to boot from disk3 instead?

Tags: hard-drive, partition

A few colleagues and I need to work out one setup CD for the product, and it has the requirement to install to the smallest disk whenever possible.

We get into a wired case that if there are 3 hard drives: 70GB, 70GB and 50GB for example, and /boot and /home and other partitions are setup properly on the 50GB drive, and when it boots up, I can F12 and choose to boot from disk3 and it goes well.

If I leave it untouched and it reboots to a blank screen with a blinking cursor --- apparently the MBR of disk1 does not direct the BIOS to boot from disk3. How can I fix this? Great thanks as have been searching the web for a whole day with little clue on this.

Here is what "fdisk -l" says about the disks, in VirtualBox as a test run.
[fdisk -l](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMPWE.png)

Comment: Install with UEFI and you'll no longer have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free (for personal use only) tool, called [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) that will allow you to move the boot sector to a new disk, as well as edit.

Comment: Thank you :-) --- can I do it from the command line?